Dirac delta derivative and homothety
Let be the strictly positive real $a>0$ and the first derivative $\delta'(x)$ of the Dirac distribution. I have come across a formula that seems wrong and that I cannot understand:
$$
\delta'(a\,x)=\frac{1}{a\,|a|}\,\delta'(x)\,. 
$$
I think the right formula is
$$
\delta'(a\,x)=\frac{1}{|a|}\,\delta'(x)\,. 
$$
But I don't know how to demonstrate it. What is the right formula?

Try to prove the formula using the definition of $\delta’$

@md2perpe The first one is the correct one.  $$\begin{align}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta'(ax) \phi(x),dx&=\frac1a\text{sgn}(a)\int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta'(y)\phi(y/a),dy\\
&=-\frac1a\text{sgn}(a)\left.\left(\frac{d\phi(y/a)}{dy}\right)\right|_{y=0}\\
&=-\frac1{a^2} \text{sgn}(a)\phi'(0)\end{align}$$

How do you define $\delta'$? Are you sure that you derive $\phi(y/a)$ before taking $y=0$ and not taking rather: $(d\phi/dy)(y/a)\vert_{y=0}=\phi'(0)$ ?

Proof ? :
From the definition of distributions derivatives, we have
$\langle\phi(x)\vert\delta'(a\,x)\rangle=
\frac{1}{a}\,\langle\phi(x)\vert[\delta(a\,x)]'\rangle=
-\frac{1}{a}\,\langle\phi'(x)\vert\delta(a\,x)\rangle$
for any test function $\phi$.
Moreover, $x=0$ is a zero of the homothety: $h:x\to{a}\,x$ ($a\neq0$), and thus, $\delta(a\,x)\equiv\frac{1}{|a|}\,\delta(x)$ since $h'(x)=a$ and the general property:
$$\delta(f(x))=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\delta(x-x_i)}{|f'(x_i)|}$$
for any differential function with $n$ zeros $x_i$ (i.e., $f(x_i)=0$) such that $f'(x_i)\neq0$.
Then, it follows that
$$\langle\phi(x)\vert\delta'(a\,x)\rangle=-\frac{1}{a\,|a|}\,\langle\phi'(x)\vert\delta(x)\rangle=-\frac{1}{a\,|a|}\,\phi'(0)\,.$$
And, moreover, from definition of $\delta$ and derivatives of distributions:
$$\phi'(0)=\langle\phi'(x)\vert\delta(x)\rangle=-\langle\phi(x)\vert\delta'(x)\rangle \,.$$
So the result:
$$\delta'(a\,x)=\frac{1}{a\,|a|}\,\delta'(x).$$ Is that right?

$\delta'(ax) \ne \frac{d}{dx}\big(\delta(ax)\big)$. The definition of distributional derivatives you gave is correct for  $\frac{d}{dx}\big(\delta(ax)\big)$, not for $\delta'(ax)$.

I have changed my "proof". Is it correct this time?

It appears to be.
